# Error during Building an APK file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I was trying to build an apk for my project but i am facing this error and

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
> >     Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzajl;

i also added **multiDexEnabled** true but still getting  error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaix.class

Below is my **Build.gradle** file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Adding support library for this demo app
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please suggest me some solution 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **SAME** version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild and Restart IDE`** .

Comment: Separate issue (though it is a problem as well). Duplicate zip files are fixed with clean and rebuild

Comment: I accepted that but earlier it was saying wait for 8 minutes you can't accept immediately

Comment: @AyushRawat yes .Ita a time validation there .

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project first - `./gradlew clean`